# How can user set the startup memory size of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am currently trying to install a new Apache IoTDB server to my settled environment. I would like to ask where the startup memory size of loTDB can be set, so I can balance the operation settings for IoTDB. Anyone know which parameter should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The start memory size of Apache IoTDB can be set using `MAX_HEAP_SIZE` and `MAX_DIRECT_MEMORY_SIZE` parameter in `conf/xxx-env.sh` path.